# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in swift2.2

Tags: swift

have declared socket with options. getting syntax error type of expression is ambiguous without more context. using swift 2.2. I'm totally stuck

```
let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "https://localhost:8080", opts: [
    "reconnects": true,
    "reconnectAttempts": 5, 
    "reconnectWait": 5, 
    "nsp": "swift", 
    "forcePolling": true,
    "cookies": nil 
])
```

**EDIT**

```
 var socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: 
               "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX")!, 
                config:["forceNew": true, 
                        "reconnectAttempts": 100, 
                        "timeout": 10000, 
                        "transports": ["websocket"] ])
```

I have followed [this](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/1.3.1/) link

Comment: Isn't is `config` rather than `opts`?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: The linked API is for Swift 1.1. Comment out and retype the method to use code completion.

Comment: @vadian thanks it is config

Comment: @vadian how to declare using config, is this a correct way-  var socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "https://localhost:8080")!, config:["forceNew": true, "reconnectionAttempts": 30, "timeout": 10000, "transports": ["websocket"] ])

Comment: The parameter `config` takes a `SocketIOClientConfiguration` object. You have to create one. Please look into the current [documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/blob/master/Source/SocketIOClient.swift).

Comment: it will be so thankfull of you if you could verify the **EDIT** part?? Thanks @vadian